# Should the word “essai” be the one used for “essay”?

Tags: choix-de-mot, terminologie, éducation

Writing an “essay” has its very specific sense. It represents something you write **in order to try to answer** a specific question.

I am French and never in my academic life have I heard the use of the word “essai” (which would be the direct translation) although it seems like a valid word to use. Instead, we tend to use these words :

- *Dissertation*
- *Composition*
- *Rédaction*

None of these seem to capture the same sense as the word “essay” but feel less weird to use than “essai”.

Is there a better term I should use?

Comment: Needs more detail on the type of essay meant, I think. P.S. si vous êtes français vous êtes invité à écrire en français ici :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Est-ce que c'est un terme qui peut être utilisé de manière plus générale ou vague.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sur de comprendre la question. En quoi le terme "essai" ne convient pas, si ce n'est que vous ne l'avez jamais utilisé jusque là ? Un essai n'étant pas la même chose qu'une dissertation, une composition ou une rédaction (bien qu'une composition puisse être composée d'un essai, si je ne me trompe) , j'imagine que vous n'avez simplement jamais eu à écrire d'essai...

Comment: @LaurentS. *composition* est un terme un peu générique pour dire... n'importe quoi. Comme une *composition florale*. Ainsi je ne dirais pas qu'une *composition* peut être composée d'un *essai*. Mais qu'un *essai* (tout comme une *dissertation*) **est** d'abord une *composition*.

Comment: *Rédaction* est un terme qui a été réservé aux exercices donnés dans l'enseignement secondaire. *Dissertation* est un exercice dans lequel on doit faire preuve d'esprit critique. On doit critiquer le sujet. Ce qui n'est pas du tout le cas d'un *essai*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les trois mots choisis sont tous particuliers à l'enseignement et reflètent des degrés croissants d'implication intellectuelle bien que sur ce point il n'y ait pas parfois une grande différence entre le premier et le second; leurs définitions (TLFi) sont données ci-dessous dans l'ordre croissant de la complexité associée à ce qu'ils représentent.

**1-Rédaction** : Exercice d'expression écrite, à partir d'un sujet imposé ou librement choisi par les élèves (individuellement ou en groupe, on parle alors de texte libre). La rédaction peut consister en une description précise, une narration, un texte d'imagination (...). Elle est prévue (...) du cours moyen de l'école primaire jusqu'au B.E.P.C.`` (Éduc. 1979).

**2-Composition** : Mise en forme des connaissances sur un sujet donné, en un temps limité et en vue d'un classement.

**3-Dissertation** : Exercice écrit, que l'on donne aux élèves ou aux étudiants, qui consiste dans la discussion argumentée d'un sujet donné.

Dans certains collèges de l'enseignement secondaire on fait déjà écrire des compositions aux élèves de 4 ième et de 3 ième. La composition est assez souvent autre chose qu'une présentation de connaissance; il peut s'agir d'un exercice écrit dans lequel la réflexion personnelle de l'élève a sa part et elle peut être assigné en tant que devoir à la maison.

Les dissertations sont des petits travaux écrits que l'on exigeait plus ou moins périodiquement des élèves à partir des classes de seconde des lycées puis ensuite dans l'enseignement supérieur et cette pratique est très probablement poursuivie de nos jours (étant déconnecté du milieu académique, je ne peux cependant pas l'affirmer); la différence en ce qui concerne ce dernier exercice écrit et les deux premier est que l'on demande de l'élève un nouvel effort dans le développement de ses aptitudes intellectuelles en cela qu'il n'est plus tenu seulement de mettre en pratique ses dons pour la description (rédaction) et ses dons d'organisation et d'imagination (composition) mais qu'il doit commencer et continuer à appliquer son pouvoir de raisonnement à des questions réelles tout en étant convainquant dans le sens d'apporter sur ces questions une nouvelle lumière dont il aura puisé les fondements, non plus comme pour la rédaction et la composition, dans son acquis général de par ses lectures et dans son imagination, mais dans des sources spécifiques desquelles il lui est demandé de citer des parties précises propres à fournir un support crédible à ce qu'il avance. Dans les études supérieures les sujets peuvent même demander une préparation spéciale dans une branche donnée : philosophie, sciences politiques, littérature, etc. Néanmoins l'activité de disserter et ainsi d'écrire des dissertations n'est pas exclusivement une activité de l'étudiant puisque les buts et méthodes de la dissertation au niveau de l'enseignement sont ceux d'une majorité des intellectuels; il se trouve cependant que l'acception correspondant à un contexte générale a été perdue (TLFi : Vieux) ou si encore retenue de nos jours elle a été pervertie, le mot « dissertation » ainsi conçu ne conférant plus exactement la même idée : selon le TLFi « P. ext., souvent péj. ou iron. Développement écrit (généralement fastidieux) d'idées, d'opinions sur un sujet didactique quelconque. Synon. discours.»

On peut maintenant considérer le mot « essai », comme la grande différence avec les trois termes précédents est que ce n'est pas un terme associé à l'enseignement. La définition du TLFi, « [En parlant d'une œuvre littér.] Ouvrage dont le sujet, sans viser à l'exhaustivité, est traité par approches successives, et généralement selon des méthodes ou des points de vue mis à l'épreuve à cette occasion. », montre que l'essai est un produit de la pensée dont la forme est plus libre que la dissertation -- *Les essais* de Montaigne, ouvrage dans lequel l'essai a sa forme par excellence, est empreint des réflexions de l'auteur. Cela est possiblement une raison qui ne rend pas l'essai si intéressant comme moyen de tester les aptitudes des étudiants, la dissertation se doit d'être un écrit assez strictement didactique, ce qui n'est pas le cas de l'essai.

Pour essayer de répondre à votre question je dois dire tout d'abord que la "validité" du mot n'est pas quelque chose de très précis; si vous voulez dire qu'il est tout à fait convenable pour remplacer les trois autres mots que vous considérez et qui ont été expliqués ci-dessus pour l'essentiel de ce qu'ils représentent, bien sûr, on doit dire selon ces explications qu'il n'est pas valide, il représente quelque chose de différent. Donc pour traduire l'anglais « essay » vous devez d'abord situer le contexte scolaire; s'il s'agit selon votre définition de « essay » dans le monde anglo-saxon (*something you write **in order to try to answer** a specific question*) alors il s'agit de « dissertation »; que le terme dans ce contexte scolaire soit utilisé selon l'acception française du mot et alors vous devez utiliser « essai » en précisant dans une note de traducteur que l'essai est une forme utilisée dans l'enseignement dont il est question.

Un terme apparenté à « essai » qui pourraient vous inspirer est  **étude**. Sa définition est « *Ouvrage, article qui contient les résultats d'une recherche* ». C'est un terme qui représente quelque chose de plus pragmatique que la dissertation ou l'essai comme le travail intellectuel associé à sa rédaction n'implique pas une grande part de théorie personnelle mais surtout un rapport de faits. L'étude est assez similaire à une forme de ce que l'on entend par « essay » dans les universités américaines. Un autre terme qui est utilisé de temps en temps est **développement**. (
exemple : On lui a demandé d'écrire un développement.) Définition du TLFi : Action de traiter une question en profondeur ou de l'exposer de manière détaillée, oralement ou par écrit; son résultat

Comment: Wow☺. Une réponse "essay". Bravo !

Answer (score 2):

*Essay* a un sens spécialisé dans l'enseignement anglophone que l'on ne retrouve pas vraiment dans le français *essai* qui s'applique plus à l’œuvre d'un écrivain que d'un étudiant.

Suivant la matière et le niveau on pourra parler de [rédaction](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9daction) (secondaire, collège), [dissertation](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/dissertation) (secondaire et supérieur, lycée et plus), [composition](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/composition) (secondaire), [étude](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tude), [présentation](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9sentation) ou [exposé](http://expos%C3%A9) (plutôt oral).

Les trois derniers sont assez neutres et génériques, comme l'*academic essay* anglais.

Comment: Donc les exemples de linguee sont erronés ? Faut-il supprimer ma réponse ?

Comment: @dimitris Les exemples ne sont pas incorrects mais quand ils utilisent essai semblent souvent provenir de textes rédigés au Canada. Il est donc possible que le sens anglais d'essay ait influencé l'essai français.

Comment: +1 pour la réponse complète et les commentaires  utiles (comme toujours ☺).

Answer (score 0):

Selon linguee il faut dire essai comme déjà mentionné

> L'étudiant doit rédiger un essai sur l'art moderne.
>
> Les étudiants doivent faire des recherches avant de rédiger un essai.

Voyez ici pour plus d'exemples

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/essay.html

Voir aussi la réponse complète de @jlliagre et les commentaires qui l'accompagne.